# How to display featured image on Wordpress category rss feed?

Tags: wordpress

This below code is working for `post` and not for `category`:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 
'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px;' ) ) . '</div>' . $content;
}
 return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

How to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

assume that all your posts are come from single.php. WordPress provides has_category() function to check if post has specific category.

So your code on single.php will need to be like something in given below

```
if( has_category('video') ){
   the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

where it checks if post has 'video' category. And if it is true then the feature image will be displayed. otherwise, it can't. Hope it will be help you.

If you want to use a plugin you can use a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/). If the plugin does not support displaying images in the rss feed you can add this in the function.php file. Something like:

```
function cattitlerss($content) {
$postcat = "";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
$postcat .= ' ('.$cat->cat_name . ')';
}
$content = do_shortcode('[wp_custom_image_category onlysrc="false" size="full" term_id="123" alt="alt :)"]');
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'cattitlerss');
```

Comment: I want images on Post category, like this http://www.sangitaskitchen.com/category/featured/feed/